# How to draw shape over centroid on specific video frames only - using "MATLAB"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, video-processing, centroid

**I'm trying to draw a circle over a centroid at a specified time of a given video.**

From what I've seen here and elsewhere, the best approach would be to read a video, get the frames, get the centroid of my object and draw a circle centered on the centroid coordinates. The bottleneck for me is **how to draw the circle on only the specified frames** (based on a timestamp I have of defined events).

In the end I have the video, this time with circles appearing (**and staying on screen**) only at specific times.

Any pointer to how best to overcome this would be very welcome and greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: That's great - what have you tried so far?

Comment: @rayryeng Hi, as per the mathworks tutorial, I've read the video and created a struct with all the frames and timestamps (in s) since the start of the video.  In a separate matrix I have the x,y coordinates (in px) of my centroid for each frame. Furthermore, my events of interest (timestamps) have also been identified (in s from start of recording). I'm just wondering about how to get to overlay a circle on the frames of interest at the centroid position.